# Run scrapy spider in loop with different arguments and output file name

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

**Problem** I need to run the scrapy spider with different urls and for each url output the result in different output file.

---

This is my first time using scrapy (more of a selenium or bs guy) and I have found various links but am kind of cold stuck.
I have this input csv file (ignore the fact that both urls are same. Just testing)

```
video_game , https://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/videogames/ref=zg_bs_nav_0
audio_game , https://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/videogames/ref=zg_bs_nav_0
```

And here is the try at script till now

```
from scrapy import cmdline
# import pandas as pd
# import scrapy
# import sys

# from amazon.spiders.video import VideoSpider
# from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
# from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
# from twisted.internet import reactor


inputfile = "./Input/amazon.csv"

# settings = get_project_settings()
# crawler = CrawlerProcess(settings)


with open(inputfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        category, url = line.split(',')
        category = category.strip()
        url = url.strip()
        outputPath = "./Output/Amazon/{0}.json".format(category)
        query = "scrapy crawl video -o " + outputPath + " -a url=" + url
        print("executing query")
        cmdline.execute(query.split())
```

Now my issue is that after **scrapy cmdline** it closes the **original script (script.py)** as well so effectively the loop runs only one time.

**Objective**

I need to read each line of csv. For each line, I will read **category** and **url** and then start the spider with that url and output the result in **{category}.json**

I have read about pipelines, open close functions in spiders, but kind of stuck.

Here, is my spider

```
class VideoSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'video'
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.in']

    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'

    def __init__(self, url = ""):
            # self.input = input  # source file name
            self.url = url
            # self.last = last

    def start_requests(self):
        # yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/videogames/ref=zg_bs_nav_0', headers={
        #     'User-Agent': self.user_agent
        # })
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url, headers={
            'User-Agent': self.user_agent
        })


    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//span[@class='aok-inline-block zg-item']/a[1]"), callback='parse_item', follow=True, process_request='set_user_agent'),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//li[@class='a-last']/a"), process_request='set_user_agent')
    )

    def set_user_agent(self, request):
        request.headers['User-Agent'] = self.user_agent
        return request

    def parse_item(self, response):
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried calling the `scrapy` command with `subprocess`?

Comment: That was my backup plan. But, I managed to do it using some setup in pipeline file